# How can I escape '"' when reading a csv-file with JDBC?

Tags: java, string, jdbc, csv, escaping

I am reading a csv-file with JDBC, using [CsvJdbc](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/). Some strings in the csv-file contains a "-char, how can I handle these situations?

When I am reading the csv-file with:

```
while (results.next()) {
    String name = results.getString("Name");
    ...
}
```

I get this SQLException, on the line where I have `while (results.next()) {`

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected '"' in position 19. Line=Mats "Matte" Tyr;12;;
```

How can I escape the "-chars so I can read the String? Or can a Java `String` not contain an "-char? Any other suggestions on how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is nothing to do with Java, but the [rules of CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Specification). A double quote needs to be escaped by doubling it to `""` and enclosing the whole field value in double quotes.

`foo,bar,"a ""quoted"" string",bang`